# Flow block is not executing, call generated from ViewModel

Tags: android, viewmodel, coroutine

Can't understand why the flow block doesn't execute and control returns back to ViewModel.

ViewModel code

```
fun getFilesFromServer() {

        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

            ftpRepository.getFilesFromServer()
                .onEach { state ->

                    when (state) {
                        is Resource.Loading -> {
                            liveData.postValue(Resource.Loading())
                        }

                }
        }
    }
```

Repository (Here the problem, control doesn't go inside flow {} block)

```
override suspend fun getFilesFromServer(): Flow<Resource<Response>> = flow {

    emit(Resource.Loading())

    ftpClient.connect(
        Constants.SERVER_IP, Constants.PORT,
        Constants.USER_NAME,
        Constants.PASSWORD,
        object : OnEZFtpCallBack<Void?> {
            override fun onSuccess(response: Void?) {

                requestFtpFileList()
            }

            override fun onFail(code: Int, msg: String) {
                
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Thanks for your time...

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to launch the flow

```
launchIn(this)
```

Complete code

```
fun getFilesFromServer() {

    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

        ftpRepository.getFilesFromServer()
            .onEach { state ->

                when (state) {
                    is Resource.Loading -> {
                        liveData.postValue(Resource.Loading())
                    }

            }
    }.launchIn(this)
}
```